Option to create new text document randomly disappears in Windows 11 and only returns after I restart my computer
On my new Windows 11 laptop, the option to create a new text file seems to disappear from the right-click menu every so often. I have to restart my computer to make this option re-appear.
Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Or is this a bug in Windows 11?

What do you mean, right-click > new > text document?

Yes. (15 characters.)

Do the other items in the New sub menu stay, or do they go away as well? About how often does the Text Document option go away? Which build of Windows 11 are you running? Have you checked for and installed all updates on your computer?

I've only seen it happen with text documents. However, this issue has not occurred again in a while. I wonder if it's related to Microsoft Store updates.

just download reg file from the source: newtext, and execute it.

Source: How to Add or Remove Default New Context Menu Items

You should quote and cite the helpful information from your external resource. Answer which contain no other information except a link to an external resource is not helpful.
